# Non Root linux troubleshoooting

Tags: linux, apache

How could be possible to check as a simple user (NOT ROOT) which port apache2 is running on, without checking /etc/apache2 or by testing with curl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [nmap](http://nmap.org) and do a scan for open ports:

```
nmap localhost
```

If you have many services you can grep for `apache2` or `http` like this:

```
nmap localhost | grep http

80/tcp    open  http
```